# Cells re-rendering in React-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a PDF export icon on all react-table rows.
When I click on 1 specific icon, for a moment I see all the icons in all the row disappear and reappear - rerendering.

I need help to find the root cause of this re-rendering and re-render only the clicked one.

The column in question is the following:

```
    {
        Header: () => null,
        accessor: 'pdf',
        Cell: ({ row }) => (
            <span className="row-pdf-icon" >
                <button onClick={() => generatePDF(row.id)} >{pdfIsLoading && row.id === clickedPdfIconInRow ? <span className="spinner" /> : <img src={pdfIcon}  />}</button>
            </span>
        ),
    },
```

And it runs this function onClick:

```
const generatePDF = useCallback(
    async (rowNumber) => {
        setClickedPdfIconInRow(rowNumber) //setState hook
        setPdfIsLoading(true) //setState hook
        await props.createFinalPDF('transaction', salesOrders[rowNumber].id) // this connects to the endpoint
        setPdfIsLoading(false) //setState hook
        setClickedPdfIconInRow(-1) //setState hook
    },
    [],
)
```

I tried to wrap the `Cell` in `memo` as well as wrapping the `generatePDF` function in a CallBack, however the rerendering of the pdf icons in all rows happens.

I think I am missing some basic memoization knowledge.

Please help

Comment: Where are you storing table (columns) config?

Comment: In the same file. Straing below the `generatePDF` function. I have `const columns = useMemo(() => [....]`